# Node.js use express.js from separate javascript files

Tags: javascript, express

I have two separate files that need to use express.js to render html

- file1.js
- file1.js

file1.js has code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/foo/bar1', (req, res) => res.json(['bar1'])
```

Can I do the same for file2.js, with a different endpoint?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/foo/bar2', (req, res) => res.json(['bar2'])
```

Or would this cause issues with express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not suppose to initiate express twice, what you can do is put the endpoints handlers in a separate files, the import it them, and use the functions...

Something like that:

```
// file1.js
modules.exports = function handler1(req, res) {
  //do stuff here
}


// file2.js
modules.exports = function handler2(req, res) {
  //do stuff here
}


// app.js
const express = require('express');
const handler1 = require('./file1');
const handler2 = require('./file2');

const app = express();

app.get('/foo/bar1', handler1);
app.get('/foo/bar2', handler2);
```